# Linux/Unix - Setting default file/folder permissions using ACL, executable permission not setting?

Tags: linux, unix, default, acl, file-permissions

I am trying to set the default permissions and group when a new file or folder is created/uploaded to my Linux (RackSpace Cloud, CentOS) server.

I want to set all children files/folders of the directory 'public' to have the following:

```
User - rwx
Group - 'ftp', rwx
Other - r-x
```

I have set the ACL (recursively) using this script:

```
setfacl -R -m u::rwx,g:ftp:rwx,d:g:ftp:rwx,o::rx public/
```

Returning the acl using getfacl displays the following:

```
# file: public/
# owner: james
# group: ftp
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:ftp:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:ftp:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

But creating a new file returns this permissions (same happens when uploading new file with user 'james' from FTP):

```
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 root  root      6 Sep  5 15:26 test.html
```

**Why is it not setting the 'x' and default group 'ftp', but setting the other permissions properly?**

Answer (score 2):

It's not setting the execute bit because files are only created with execute permission if the application explicitly requests it.  Since it makes no sense to make an .html file executable, whatever program created it did not request execute permission to be added, so it has no execute permission.  Consequently, execute permission from the default ACL *effectively* only applies to directories, not to files.

As for why the default group is not set to `ftp`, this is more subtle.  The default ACL is just that -- an ACL.  It's not a default group ownership.  As such it shows up not in `ls` but in `getfacl`:

```
# mkdir public
# setfacl -R -m u::rwx,g:ftp:rwx,d:g:ftp:rwx,o::rx public/
# getfacl public
# file: public
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:ftp:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:ftp:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

# echo hello, world > public/test.html
# ls -l public
total 4
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 root root 13 Aug 29 13:00 test.html
# getfacl public/test.html 
# file: public/test.html
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r-x                      #effective:r--
group:ftp:rwx                   #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

Note that ftp can access the file just fine while others cannot:

```
# cd public
# su nobody -s /bin/bash -C "touch test.html"
touch: cannot touch `test.html': Permission denied
# su ftp -s /bin/bash -C "touch test.html"
#
```